# How do I get an NSArray of all the filenames of all .png resources on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I've added a several .png files as resources to my project.  How can I get an array of their names without having to hardcode them?

Comment: Voting to close: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513480/how-do-i-enumerate-and-load-resources-in-an-iphone-app (as pointed out by Boot To The Head)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, it works in a Mac OS X application.

```
NSArray *files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

See also: [How do I enumerate and load resources in an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513480/how-do-i-enumerate-and-load-resources-in-an-iphone-app)